# Not able to resolve a new object in angular ui modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to implement angular UI modal and trying to set few default values before create person screen is opened. Say a new person object like below:

```js
  var person = {};
  person.name = 'default';
```

In this function

```js
modalCtrl.open = function(size) {

    var person = {};
    person.name = 'default';

    console.log('person-->' + person);
    console.log('person.name-->' + person.name);

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      scope: $scope,
      resolve: {
        person: function() {
          return person;
        }
      }
    });
```

I can do the same thing in update flow if the object is passed by a called.

My assumption is that I should be able to create a new object and resolve it to display few default values on create screen. Does anyone know why I can't do it? Here is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XLrbQpDoV8bx1vktbygx?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve it.. just need to add person as a dependency to the modal instance controller

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'person',
  function($scope, $modalInstance, person) {
    alert(person.name);
    $scope.ok = function() {
      $modalInstance.close($scope.person);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  }
]);
```